# Having no money, I want to help you. (what does this mean?)

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Having no money, I want to help you. (What does this mean?)

I think it is: Although I have no money, I want to help you. (i.e., as a concessive clause)

Comment: It's closer to:**Because I have no money, I want to help you**. Although the grammar is fine, the sense is puzzling. Being without money is not regarded as an incentive for helping people, unless it is for reward.

Comment: What about "Although having no money, I want to help you".

Comment: Even though I have no money, I wanna help you. I don't have any money, but I am willing to help you.